# Generic helper for record

Tags: delphi, generics, helper, delphi-10.1-berlin

Currently I have many records with helper methods like this:

```
TRec1 = packed record
  S1: string;
  S2: string;
  procedure FromJSON(const AJSON: string);
  function  ToJSON: string;
end;

procedure TRec1.FromJSON(const AJSON: string);
begin
  RecordLoadJSON(Self, StringToUTF8(AJSON), TypeInfo(TRec1));
end;

function TRec1.ToJSON: string;
begin
  Result := UTF8ToString(RecordSaveJSON(Self, TypeInfo(TRec1)));
end;

TRec2 = packed record
  S1: string;
  I1: string;
  procedure FromJSON(const AJSON: string);
  function  ToJSON: string;
end;

procedure TRec2.FromJSON(const AJSON: string);
begin
  RecordLoadJSON(Self, StringToUTF8(AJSON), TypeInfo(TRec2));
end;

function TRec2.ToJSON: string;
begin
  Result := UTF8ToString(RecordSaveJSON(Self, TypeInfo(TRec2)));
end;
```

As you can see all records contain the same methods ToJSON and FromJSON.
This methods contain completely the same code except TypeInfo()

Any way to use generics for this and do not declate this methods for every records?

Comment: You can't do this with a helper. Make a pair of functions to do this. And BTW, packing the record does no good, it just leads to the record being misaligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Records or classes?**
Even though Delphi has support for methods, records are still 2nd class citizens because there is no support for record inheritance.
Classes have all the features records have plus the full set of OOP features, so they are often a better choice. However you need to deal with the reference semantics that requires managing the creation and destruction of classes manually on non-ARC platforms vs the care-free value semantics of records that have automatic clean-up.

**Non generics solution (using a class)**
Declare the string containers as a class and use inheritance.

```
TRec1 = class(TPersistent)
  S1: string;
  S2: string;
  procedure FromJSON(const AJSON: string);
  function  ToJSON: string;
end;

TRec2 = class(TRec1)
end;

procedure TRec1.FromJSON(const AJSON: string);
begin
  RecordLoadJSON(Self, StringToUTF8(AJSON), Self.ClassInfo);
end;

function TRec1.ToJSON: string;
begin
  Result := UTF8ToString(RecordSaveJSON(Self, Self.ClassInfo));
end;
```

All classes inherited from `TPersistent` have RTTI and thus the `self.classinfo` works.
You may need to revise the `RecordSaveJSON` call depending on your needs.

**Generics solution**
If you have RTTI enabled for your unit `{$M+}` and you must use records, simply use methods outside of the record and feed the record type as a generic parameter.

```
TRec1 = record
  data: typex;
  ....
end;

TDoJSONThings = record     //helper record for any and all types with RTTI.
  procedure FromJSON<T:record>(var Data: T; const JSON: string); static;
  function ToJSON<T:record>(const [ref] Data: T): string; static;
end;

procedure TDOJSONThings.FromJSON<T>(var Data: T; const JSON: string); static;
var
  pt: PTypeInfo;
begin
  pt:= TypeInfo(T);
  RecordLoadJSON(Data, StringToUTF8(AJSON), pt);
end;

function TDOJSONThings.ToJSON<T:record>(const [ref] Data: T): string; static;
var
  pt: PTypeInfo;
begin
  pt:= TypeInfo(T);
  Result:= UTF8ToString(RecordSaveJSON(Data, pt));
end;
```

**Remarks**
Using a `record helper` (as in `THelper = record helper for TRec1`) will not work, because that will only work for `TRec1` and records sadly do not support inheritance.

It would have been better to use stand-alone methods, but Delphi does not allow generic methods that are not part of a record or class.

Oh and please drop the 1970's `packed record` style construct. It serves no purpose but to make your code slower by misaligning it.

Comment: Your code based in generic methods cannot work. Ask yourself whether TDoJSONThings is the same as T. Classes vs records is not a decision about performance primarily. It's a decision about value vs reference assignment semantics.

Comment: Oops, yes missed the `self` reference.

Comment: Trying to test sample with record: TDOJSONThings.ToJSON<TRecTest2>(R2); (R2: TRecTest2) and got compiler error: [dcc32 Error] E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor

This is my declaration, which works:
  TJSON = record
    class procedure From<T:record>(var Data: T; const AJSON: string); static;
    class function &To<T:record>(const [ref] Data: T): string; static;
  end;

Comment: Yes, you meant to make this be a static class method. Johan, you could have made more effort here. Alex, you can edit the answer to correct it. That is how we roll here.

Comment: Packed records are not `1970's packed record style construct`, they are required to avoid compiler alignment if records mapped for example to file structures.